# I am using fabric python library using that I create the 50 times ssh connection I need it but I get following error

Tags: python

While using fabric library in python and forming ssh connection I am getting following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 1923, in run
<type 'exceptions.AttributeError'>: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'error'

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 1923, in run
<type 'exceptions.AttributeError'>: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'error'
```

Comment: can you share code snippet as well ?

Comment: .execute_list_of_commands(variables.USERNAME, variables.IP, variables.PASSWORD, cmds, variables.EXEC_PATH)
 calling this stmt in whole sorce code minimum 40-50 time

Comment: please update question itself with code along with how you're doing connect operation.

Comment: execute_list_of_commands() is my function using that i do the ssh to remote machine using fabric library.

Comment: with settings(hide('running','warnings','stdout','stderr'),host_string=host_string,warn_only=True): # using host_string login to the remote machine.
            env.password=password   # set the password of corresponding remote machine.

            with cd('%s' %cd_option):

Comment: solve the issue by using connections in fabric python library .store all the ip in cache by default then at end of script disconnect from all remote machine by using disconnect_all() method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solve the issue by using connections in fabric python library .store all the ip in cache by default then at end of script disconnect from all remote machine by using disconnect_all() method.